# How to add icon/image to listitem of ListView

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have created listview by using arrayadpter i add arraryadapter to listview contaning string array but i m unable to add icon to eatch listitem
help me out...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [free excerpt](http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf) from one of my books that discusses the techniques involved. In a nutshell, you will need to extend your `Adapter` class (e.g., `ArrayAdapter`, `CursorAdapter`) and take direct control over the creation of rows, so you can apply your desired business logic.