# How to make a listview without icon on the right?

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

How to make a listview without icon on the right? I want to change apperance of my read-only and normal listviews in jQuery Mobile. I am compiling app with PhoneGap.

I read similar posts like: [How to add icon/image to listitem of ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2200052/how-to-add-icon-image-to-listitem-of-listview), but couldn't get my answer.

Comment: Usually the lists with an icon have a link, you can create list without any link (= read only lists): http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/lists/lists-readonly.html . Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know how to do the same thing with list having links?

Comment: I re-edited my previous answer. Have a look at the second part of my post :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the lists with an icon on the right have a link.

You can create read-only lists which do not include linked content.

You can check the online doc for more information:

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/lists/lists-readonly.html

**Example of code:**

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a">
            <li>Acura</li>
            <li>Audi</li>
            <li>BMW</li>
            <li> Cadillac</li>
            <li> Ferrari</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

If you want to keep the links, you just need to add `data-icon="false"` to your `<li>` tags:

**Example of code:**

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="p1">
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="a" >                   
                <li data-icon="false"><a href="#p2">Go to page 2</a></li>
                <li data-icon="false"><a href="#p3">Go to page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="p2">
        Hello! This is page 2!!!
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="p3">
        Hello! This is page 3!!!
    </div>
</body>
```

Hope this helps